# TabItem style based on ViewModel type

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, tabcontrol, styling, tabitem

I was able to achieve binding of my **TabItems** to a collection of **ViewModels** and use **DataTemplates** to style contents of each type. What I cannot do is find a way for **styling TabItem** itself (header etc.) based on the selected ViewModel.

EDIT: 
You may ask why would I want to have different styles for my TabItems, well, one of the reasons is for instance that I will have one TabItem always open that should not have a close button.

Comment: You should use a `CustomControl` instead. You can have a dependency property for whether the close button is visible. [Here you go.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc295235.aspx)